# Why my nic will up after insmod the driver,I didn't run the "ifconfig eth up"?

Tags: networking, drivers, kernel, nic

There is no file in /etc/network/interface.d and /etc/network/interfaces.
Is there any other configura file?
I am using ubuntu 20.04.I think if my nic driver in /lib/module/`uname -r`/kernel/driver,the ubuntu start up will install the driver,but why it will up my nic?

Comment: In a desktop install, the interface is brought up in Network Manager. In a server, it is brought up in netplan. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: There is a netplan script in /etc/netplan, thanks!